# 3 fields composite primary key (unique item) in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am trying to create a table to store invoice line items in DynamoDB. Let's say the item is defined by `CompanyCode`, `InvoiceNumber` and `LineItemId`, amount and other line item details.

A unique item is defined by the combination of the first 3 attributes. Any 2 of those attributes can be same for the different items. What should I select as the Hash Attribute and the Range Attribute?

Comment: How do you plan to query these records?  Will you always have the CompanyCode+InvoiceNumber+LineItemId for queries?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the query and also I need to query on only CompanyCode.

Answer (score 77):

### Some Intro

For efficiency I would propose totally different design. With NoSQL databases (and DynamoDB is not different) we always need to consider the access patterns first. Also, if possible we should strive to fit all our data within same table and several indexes. From what we have from OP and his comments, these are the two access patterns:

1. For a company X, get complete invoice Y (including all items or range of items) [based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620215/3-fields-composite-primary-key-unique-item-in-dynamodb/32634335#comment53091455_32620215) ]
2. Get all invoices for company X [ based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620215/3-fields-composite-primary-key-unique-item-in-dynamodb/32634335#comment53098720_32620215) ]

We now wonder what is a good Primary Key? Translates to question what is a good Partition Key (PK) and what is a good Sort Key (SK) and which secondary indexes do we need to create and of what kind (local or global)? Some reminders:

- Primary Key can be on one column or composite
- Composite primary key consists of Partition Key and Sort Key
- Partition key is used as input to the hashing function that will determine partition of the items
- Sort key can also be composite, which allows us to model one-to-many relationships in DynamoDB as given in one of the comments links: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html
- When creating query on the table or index, you always need to use '=' operator on the Partition Key
- When querying ranges on Sort Key you have option for `KeyConditionExpression` which provides you with [set of operators for sorting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) and everything in between (one of them being function `begins_with (a, substr)` )
- You are also allowed to use `FilterExpression` if you need to further refine the Query results (filter on the projected attributes)
- Local Secondary Indexes (LSI) have same Partition Key but different Sort Key than your original table and give you different view of your data, organized according to an alternative Sort Key
- Global Secondary Indexes (GSI) have different Partition Key and different Sort Key than your original table and give you completely different view on data
- All items with the same partition key are stored together, and for composite Primary  keys, are ordered by the sort key value. DynamoDB splits partitions by sort key if the collection size grows bigger than 10 GB.

### Back To Modeling

It is obvious that we are dealing with multiple entities that need to be modeled and fit into the same table. To satisfy condition of Partition Key being unique on the table, `CompanyCode` comes as a natural Partition Key - so I would ensure that is unique. If not then you need to ask yourself how can you model the second access pattern?

Assuming we have established uniqueness on the `CompanyCode` let's simplify and say that it comes in the form of an e-mail (or could be domain or just a code, but I will use email for demonstration).

- Relationship between Company and Invoices is always 1:many.
- Relationship between Invoice and Items is always 1:many.

I propose design as in the image below:
[image: Proposed design in DynamoDB]

- With PK being `CompanyCode` and SK being `InvoiceNumber` can store all attributes about that invoice for that company.
- Nothing prevents me to also add record where the SK is `Customer` which allows me to store all attributes about the company.
- With GSI1 , we will create reverse lookup where GSI1PK is my tables SK (`InvoiceNumber`) and my GSI1SK is my tables PK (`CompanyCode`).
- I am using same table to store line items with PK being `LineItemId` and SK being `CompanyCode` (still unique)
- For Item entity items my GSI1PK is still `InvoiceNumber` and my GSI1SK is `LineItemId` which is tables PK so its same as for Invoice entity items.

Now the access patterns supported with this:

- If I want to get invoice Y for company X and all the items (access pattern 1): Query the table where `CompanyCode=X` and use `KeyConditionExpression` with `=` operator on the Sort Key `InvoiceNumber`. If I want to get all the items tied to that invoice, I will project `Items` attribute using `ProjectionExpression`.
- By retrieving all the items with previous query for company X and invoice Y, I can now run `BatchGetItem` API call (using my unique composite key `LineItemId+CompanyCode`) on table to get all items belonging to that particular invoice of that particular customer. (this comes with some constraints of [BatchGetItem API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html))
- To support access pattern 2, I will do a query with `CompanyCode=X` on PK and use `KeyConditionExpression` on the SK with `begins_with (a, substr)` function/operator to get  only invoices for company X and not the metadata about that company. That will give me all invoices for given company/customer.
- Additionally, with above GSI1, for any given `InvoiceNumber` I can easily select all the line items that belong to that particular invoice. **REMEMBER:**  [The key values in a global secondary index do not need to be unique](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) - so in my GSI1 I could have had easily invoice_1 -> (item_1, item_2) and then another invoice_1 -> (item_1,item_2) but the difference between two items in GSI would be in the SK (it would be associated with different `CompanyCode` (but for demonstration purposes I used invoice_1 and invoice_2).

Answer (score 36):

I believe [the first option offered by @georgeaf99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32634335/1480391) won't work, because if you do it that way, then `CompanyCode` has to be unique in the table. Therefore, there would only be one item allowed per company. I think the second solution is the only real way to do it.

You can use `CompanyCode` as the Hash Key, and then all other fields that combine to make the item unique (in this case `InvoiceNumber` and `LineItemId`) need to be somehow **combined into one value** (such as concatenation with a field delimiter), which would be your Range Key. Unfortunately that is kind of ugly, but that's the nature of a NoSQL database like DynamoDB. However, it will allow you to successfully store records with the correct uniqueness. When reading the records back, if you don't want to parse the combined field back out to its individual parts, then you'll have to add additional separate fields for `InvoiceNumber` and `LineItemID`.

If you don't have a large number of invoices per company, you can query by only the Hash Key and do the filtering on the client side. If you have a large number of invoices per company and need to be able to query only the items for a single invoice, then I would create a secondary index on CompanyCode and InvoiceNumber.

Answer (score 10):

As I'm sure you have figured out you cannot have more than two attributes form your primary key (hash+range). Thus, depending on the type of queries you will be performing and the size of your data you can structure your table in different ways.

(Optimized for the query type you mentioned above: only `CompanyCode` & all 3)

Best sol'n for small/medium size data sets:

- Hash Key: `CompanyCode`
- Perform the query using only `CompanyCode` and
  then filter your results on the other two attributes

---

Optimal solution for large data sets:

- Hash Key: `CompanyCode`
- Range Key: `InvoiceNumber`+`LineItemId`
- This allows you to query only on an index, but the table structure is pretty ugly

Comment: Or maybe CompanyCode+InvoiceNumber as hash, LineItemId as range, and add secondary index for CompanyCode. That way you can query by company, and you can query a specific invoice for a specific company. There seems to be no need to query by invoice number alone, as presumably the same invoice number can be used with multiple companies.

Comment: +1 to jarmod's suggestion.  Having CompanyCode+InvoiceNumber affords better cardinality and ultimately scalability in your application.  E.G. if a CompanyCode gets ton of writes for new invoices, that one hash-key / partition is going to get slammed versus distributing it through your table

Comment: @jarmod Is there a way Dynamodb itself takes care of that concatenation and we just can pass those fields as separate fields? Also I want to access those fields as separate ones in the secondary index without storing it as duplicates again in other field.

Comment: I like that solution also. It works well if you don't mind storing the data twice and sending extra data on updates as well. To my knowledge there is no way to have one field be part of two indexes.

Comment: @HHH I don't believe that Dynamo will do the concatenation for you. If you want to query them individually then I think you're going to have to store and index them outside of the hash key. If you are writing so many invoices to companies that this duplication of data causes a problem then that would be a very nice problem to have ;-)

Comment: Can you elaborate what `InvoiceNumber`+`LineItemId` means? Is this a string field where you are literally concatenating them? This article mentions "composite sort keys" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html and the example `[country]#[region]#[state]#[county]#[city]#[neighborhood]` and that you could "make efficient range queries for a list of locations at any one of these levels of aggregation". if that is a concat,  then how, using `CONTAINS` or `BEGINS_WITH` ? Seems inefficient

Comment: What in the world does "sol'n" mean? Is that supposed to be shorthand for "solution"?