# Java Annotation for composite Range Keys in DDB

Tags: java, annotations, amazon-dynamodb, lombok

I have a `my_table` with a composite sort key made of two combined attributes `id` and `model_name` (i.e., `id_model_name`, similarly from what is done here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620215/3-fields-composite-primary-key-unique-item-in-dynamodb) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)).

So I created this Java model:

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my_table")
public class TableModel {

    private static final String COMPOSITE_KEY_SEPARATOR = "_";

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "id")
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "model_name")
    private String modelName;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "id_model_name")
    public String getIdModelName() {
        return String.format("%s%s%s", id, COMPOSITE_KEY_SEPARATOR, modelName);
    }

    // more stuff...
}
```

However I'm getting:

`DynamoDBMappingException: DRTFacet[id_model_name]; could not unconvert attribute`

Notice that there is no `String idModelName` field, because it could mess up with `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@Builder` (since it's a derived field). Is it because this field is missing (together with a setter method?). How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that providing a dummy setter solved the problem:

```
public void setIdModelName(final String idModelName) {}
```

Comment: You didn't had any problem with reads? For me, when I tried to load a row it failed (using dbMapper), I think bc couldn't found how to map that rangeKey.