# Can I model data that require 3 columns to uniquely identify row in dynamodb?

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm coming from SQL and struggling to model NoSQL (dynamodb), even some simple datasets. Asking for some guidance to model this data in dynamodb.

My data (as shown below) can only be uniquely identified using the first 3 columns: `barcode`, `date` and `type`. See the first and second row. Using Partition Key and Sort Key the second row can't be inserted.

It seems Secondary keys won't solve it.

Is there a way to model this data or should I stick with SQL?

| barcode (Partiton key) | date (Sort Key) | **type** (what key??) | value | obs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz123 | 06/08/2021 | type1 | *random* | *random* |
| xyz123 | 06/08/2021 | type2 | *random* | *random* |
| xyz123 | 12/12/2021 | type1 | *random* | *random* |
| wsr456 | 12/12/2021 | type5 | *random* | *random* |

Comment: You can use `{{barcode}}-{{date}}-{{type}}` as the partition key to get around with this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3 fields composite primary key (unique item) in Dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620215/3-fields-composite-primary-key-unique-item-in-dynamodb)

Comment: short answer, yes - I wouldn't design it the way @jellycsc suggests though, but you can combine date and type for your sort key. To learn more about DDB design I can recommend https://www.dynamodbbook.com/ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiP2e-g-r4g

Comment: Thanks for answering. For now, I'm going with `date#type` as sort key.

Answer (score 2):

The learning curve for NoSQL can be steep, as you're finding.

The NoSQL approach to data modeling dictates that you confront your applications unique access patterns *first*.  From there, you decide how to store your data depending on how your application needs to query the information.

"How do I model this data?" is only part of the question you need to ask.  The more complete question is "How do I model this data *given* the specific needs of my application?"  NoSQL databases store data in a *denomralized* fashion, which means you need to put more thought into your data access needs *up front*.  DynamoDB makes it *super* easy to put data into the database; resist this temptation.  Instead, stop to think about what types of queries your application needs to support.

In your example, you appear to be storing items that have barcodes.  Are you building an inventory system?  Do you need to fetch the most recent inventory by date?  Do you need to fetch your inventory by type?  Do you need to fetch inventory that is below some threshold?  The answers to these sorts of questions will determine what your data model looks like.

Comment: It takes a little longer to learn nosql indeed. I'm starting to pick it up. I'm taking the slower approach as you suggested.

Comment: You're in good company, the process is not easy!  Like many things, you'll get better at it with practice.  Look up blog posts and youtube videos from Alex Debrie, he's among the best content creators around DynamoDB.  His content will put you on the fast track to understanding DynamoDB.  Good luck!